# Using python requests module to hit API, how do I filter what's returned when using 'print r.json'?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm a noob with python and requests.  I've searched for an answer to my question, but haven't been able to find what I need, so I apologize in advance if I missed it.  The following code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://some.api.url.here')
print r.json()
```

returns the json from the url I'm hitting in this format:

```
{u'status': u'success', u'data': [{u’field1': u'', u’field2’: u’xxxxx’, u’field3’: u’yyyyy’, u’field4’: u’zzzzz’}, {u’field1’: u'', u’field2’: u’aaaaa’, u’field3’: u’sssss’, u’field4’: u’qqqqq’}, {u'field1': u'', u'field2': u’aaaaa’, u'field3': u’bbbbb’, u'field4': u’ggggg’}, {u'field1': u'', u'field2': u’hhhhh’, u'field3': u’fffff’, u'field4': u’ddddd’}] }
```

I'd like to print only the 'field1' fields, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Comment: Same way as any other dictionary. There is nothing special here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should study how `json` and python's dictionary work.

```
# Get data into a dictionary
json_data = r.json()
# Now you access the 'data' by
print json_data['data']
# [{'field1': 'value1'}, {'field1': 'value2'}]

# The above is a list
# To access it,
print json_data['data'][0]['field1']
# value1
print json_data['data'][1]['field1']
# value2
```

The above was for your understanding, a simpler way would be

```
d = json_data['data']
for f in d:
    print d['field1']
```

This will output

```
value1
value2
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer.  It was clear and concise and now I understand this better.  One thing though, the 'print d['field1']' returned "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str".  I changed that line to 'print f['field1']' and I got the output I wanted.  Thanks again for your help and patience.